# Rendering - Save Intermediate

Tags: rendering

When I render an image that could take hours to finish is there a way that I can save the render  at every hour, so that if my computer crashes I do not loose everything?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Save the file? Or save the image chunks that are rendered? I don't see a use for that since you can't really control the order in which chunks are rendered...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Save buffers]

In the performance panel (for either BI or Cycles), there's a *Save Buffers* option which will save the render to a layered EXR file in your temp directory quite often. I could be mistaken, but I think it's each time it starts a new tile.

On windows, this temp directory is located at `C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Temp\` by default, but will use the path specified in *User Preferences > File > Temp* if set.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem (rendertask of 3 days). What you should do is render not a movie but individual pictures. If there is a crash you can tell Blender not to overwrite old images and start where it crashed. In the end you have to do an extra step to generate a movie from those images, but this can also be done from within Blender.
I found a great tutorial that also discusses this subject
https://youtu.be/LPbUuMs2i20

Comment: Could you explain how? Perhaps detail the procedure steps, and show a few screenshots of relevant settings